# Get random records invariant on same day

Tags: sql

I have the folowing SQL table:

```
Create table Post (
  Id int primary key not null,
  Title nvarchar (80) not null
)
```

I need to get 4 random rows from the table but they would always be the same for the same Day.

How can this be done?

Comment: What do you mean "for the same Day"? There's no date information in the table definition you showed.

Comment: I mean, if i get 4 random records now or in 1 hour they would be the same. But if i get 4 records tomorrow they would be different because the query was on a different day

Comment: What is the query you're using to select the random rows, currently?

Comment: I am ordering the records by a Guid and taking 4. This gives me 4 random records which are always different

Comment: So you're generating a temporary GUID for each row, ordering by this and selecting only the top 4, is that correct (it would probably help even more to see the actual query)? The problem is likely in the way your GUID function generates the values. Where is this function coming from, and which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Side note, as demonstrated by RADAR's answer, even if you are not using MS SQL, the concept he's showing is that most database systems have some method of retrieving random rows. Maybe do a search for how to retrieve random rows for your RDBMS and see what comes up (bet you anything there'll be lots of SO posts about it).

Answer (score 1):

In MS SQL Server, you can use `RAND` function with current day of the year as the seed

For a specified seed value, the result returned is always the same.

```
RAND(DATEPART(dayofyear, GETDATE()))
```